# Replacing NA for mean df column by using a for-loop not working and not raising any error in R

Tags: r, dataframe, class, for-loop, replace

I am trying to replace NA values for mean df columns based on column data class,

I am currently using a for-loop however it does not work and it does not
raise any error into R console

Here's the code I am using:

```
## data ##

df <- structure(list(
      name = c("Bob", "John", "Maria", "Emma", "Greg"),
      salary = c(1000.234, 2000.4322, 3000.133, 4000.765, NA),
      age = c(NA, NA, 33, 27, 54),
      tenure = c(7, 8, NA, NA, NA)),
      class = "data.frame", 
      row.names = c(NA, 
                    -5L))

## for-loop ##

for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
   if(class(df[[i]]) == "integer"){
  
 df[is.na(df[,i]), i] <- round(mean(df[,i], na.rm = TRUE), 
                                                           digits = 0)
   }
    else if(class(df[[i]]) == "numeric") {
      
      df[is.na(df[,i]), i] <- mean(df[, i], na.rm = TRUE)
    } 
      else {
             break
      }
}
```

Is there any other way to apply this for-loop?

Comment: But a first guess - remove the `else{break}`. `break` stops a loop. You *could* use `else{next}` to go to the next iteration, but it is not needed - at the end of the loop it will automatically go to the next iteration anyway. `next` is used if you want to skip the rest of a loop and go directly to the next iteration.

Comment: @Gregor Thomas, already added a structure

Comment: @Gregor Thomas, I changed break for next and the next warning message arises: `Warning messages:
1: In if (class(df[[i]]) == "integer") { :
  la condición tiene longitud > 1 y sólo el primer elemento será usado
2: In if (class(df[[i]]) == "numeric") { :
  la condición tiene longitud > 1 y sólo el primer elemento será usado`

Comment: `class() == ` is a bad pattern because `class` can have multiple values. Replace `class(df[[i]]) == "integer"` with `is.integer(df[[i]])` and replace `class(df[[i]]) == "numeric"` with `is.numeric(df[[i]])`

Comment: @Gregor Thomas, thanks it works now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(i in 1:ncol(df)) {
  if (is.integer(df[[i]])) {
    df[is.na(df[[i]]), i] <- round(mean(df[[i]], na.rm = TRUE), digits = 0)
  }
  else if(is.numeric(df[[i]])) {
    df[is.na(df[[i]]), i] <- mean(df[[i]], na.rm = TRUE)
  }
}

df
#    name   salary age tenure
# 1   Bob 1000.234  38    7.0
# 2  John 2000.432  38    8.0
# 3 Maria 3000.133  33    7.5
# 4  Emma 4000.765  27    7.5
# 5  Greg 2500.391  54    7.5
```